# How could I add multiple headers to a Matlab txt document

Tags: matlab

I currently have code that places data collected from a simulation into various txt documents separated by time. However, I would like to add various headers and other information into each document. How would that be possible? Some of the information would be a variable (such as previous ones I put in) and others would be constant for each one.

```
for nn = 1:TMAX/10

  fid = fopen(['word' num2str(nn) '.txt'],'w');
 %x and y are defined here for the entire code and for x y and theta to
 %have a close access to print 
  x = x + vel*cos(theta)*dt;
  y = y + vel*sin(theta)*dt;
  fprintf(fid, '%4.5f\t%4.5f\t%4.5f\n', x,y,theta);

  fclose(fid);
```

ideally the new code would return

1. ITEM: TIMESTEP (is the header)
   1000 (i a variable base off of time (is nn/10))
2. ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS (another header)
   32000 (Variable N)
3. ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp (another header)
   0 54 (is variable 0-L)
   0 54 (is variable 0-L)
   0 6.283185307 (is constant 0 to 2 pi)
4. ITEM: ATOMS id x y Theta (another header)
5. the last line that isn't written is that I would like to number each particle. Ie Currently the code returns a matrix of the three variables X Y Theta in three columns and I would like the rows to be labeled 1-N.
   How could any of this be done? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can't you do all of this using `fprintf`, or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Maybe, but how could I write it? like I would like these things (except for item 4) to be underneath all of the other information that textfile saves. Item four, should be the headers for the three columns the code generates. I am just unsure how to do that